# Logical negation operator in F#? (!-equivalent)

Tags: f#, functional-programming

What is the equivalent to the C# "!" operator in F#?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

According to ["Foundations of F#"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597575), page 61:

> F# uses a function called `not` for Boolean "not" operations.

Answer (score 5):

See [Core.Operators Module (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353754%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more.

Comment: reference docs are now here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353754(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score -2):

you can also use "<>"

Comment: I don't know why this is being downvoted. "<>" is a valid alternative in the sense of 'not equals'

Comment: Not equals isn't quite the same as not. Not equals is binary (having two sides) as in a <> b, wheras not is unary (having one side), as in 'not a'. You were probably downvoted because your answer *looks so right*, but it's actually misleading.