# F# if not condition

Tags: f#

What is the best way in F# to write an if not condition?

Right now I'm writing it like this:

```
if condition <> true then do
```

Is there any other shorter way to write it? Like using the ! operator?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239888/logical-negation-operator-in-f-equivalent

Comment: That's alright, it is an important question, because of the caveat in my answer, bit of a pitfall for those that are not aware of `<>`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Ocaml, you can use the "not" keyword:

```
if not condition then ...
```

Hopefully works too with F#.

Comment: +1: yep, works in F#. Surround conditions with parens as needed.

Comment: AH! I tried this earlier but failed to comprehend the error it was telling me. Now it's working fine using the keyword not. Thanks so much!

Comment: I use the <| operator with not, like this: "if not <| expression then ..." to avoid parentheses.

Answer (score 34):

if you consider that not is also a function, then you can pipe your condition into it to avoid parenthesis like so:

```
if not <| condition param1 param2 then ...
```

reason being is if your condition function takes arguments, you don't need to do

```
not (condition param1 param2)
```

it's probably a little cleaner to do it the first way since it seems f# is in favor of pipes instead of parenthesis for operator precedence.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the tip on this. I had no idea you could use the pipe to do this.

Comment: I love this, `if not <| condition param1 param2 then ...` fits well into F#'s brevity, as both easily typed, read, and modified. Parenthesis are so OO ;-)

Comment: "Parenthesis are so OO"
Lisp would like to have a word with you ;)

Answer (score 6):

There is the [not function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370457.aspx), but it only works with boolean variables.

So you can say:

```
if (not condition) then do
```

But that would not work with other types as in C-style languages.

Do not use `!` by accident, as it is still an operator in F#, it is a [dereference on a mutable reference cell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353582.aspx).

See the [full operator documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353754%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score -19):

I don't know F# but in C, using the ! operator I'd write:

```
if(!condition) { ... }
```

which is the same as

```
if(condition == false) { ... }
```

Comment: `!` is operator to get value of a reference cell in F#. you need the `not` function.

Comment: @Tomas Petricek, I began with "I don't know F#". I saw he did if condition <> true then ... so I guessed "maybe he doesn't know he can negate condition and get the same result"

Comment: Good point, though I think it could do with an edit to make that abundantly clear.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. The issue I was having was with a more complex if statement that had multiple conditions. I knew about the not keyword but I wasn't formulating the statement correctly. After asking and reading your answers I took more time to carefully go through the code and figured out where I was going wrong. Thanks a bunch guys!